# Commands for dates equivalent to Ctrl+; and Ctrl+: shortcuts

Tags: excel, vba, date, time, keyboard-shortcuts

<kbd>Ctrl+;</kbd> fills in the current date in the active cell.

I tried to record this but it shows something like `ActiveCell.Value="8/16/2016"`, while I expected something like `ActiveCell.Value=Current_Date()`.

Are there VBA functions for "Current date" and/or "Current time" which are equivalent to Excel shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl+;</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+:</kbd>?

Comment: To the person who is editing this post: I've been banned from reviewing, so I can't approve your modifications. However I'd like you to put back the "keyboard-shortcuts" tag as it is relevant for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the Date and Time functions on: http://www.classanytime.com/mis333k/sjdatetime.html

So `ActiveCell.Value=Date`is what you are looking for.

Comment: Ctrl+; and Ctrl+: commands do not yield a function but instead they return a value. Of course, there could be a hook to check if the user is recording a macro then instead of returning a date string, return the date function but I guess it's just how Excel works.